# @IBOutlet implemented as property wrapper?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I was checking the concept of property wrapper in Swift 5.1, and in Swift UI, and came across the concept of property wrapper like @state, @ObservedObject and @Published, which are implemented as property wrapper (as far as I know).

So just a question from curiosity is originally Apple implemented @IBOutlet as property 
wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `@IBOutlet` is a "Declaration Attribute", documented [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html).

Answer (score 0):

**IBOutlet** is a keyword which is added to a variable declaration. It’s an indicator. It does not affect the declaration in any way. However, when the Interface Builder sees it, it will allows a programmer to set this variable through the “outlet” mechanism inside Interface Builder.